# Generators and threads: How can I access data yielded by threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, generator

```
import Queue
import threading
import time

def work(q):
    while True:
        print threading.current_thread().getName() + ":" + str(time.clock())
        yield q.get()
        q.task_done()



def main():
    q = Queue.Queue()

    for i in range(10):
        q.put(i)

    for i in range(3):
        t = threading.Thread(target=work, args=(q,))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    q.join()
```

In this example how can I consume the data `yield`ed by the threads which are started by the main thread ?

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Main thread starts a feeder thread that feeds data to be consumed in q1.
2. Main thread starts worker threads that consume data from q1 and write outcomes to q2.
3. Either main thread or consumer thread (only 1) consume data in q2 and `yield` it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Work threads cannot be generators.

Threads *must* be functions that operate on their own; they are started by the `threading.Thread()` class and from there on work independently. Using a generator object there makes little sense.

You are in essence trying to mix concurrency models here. Using a generator *in* a thread is fine, using a generator *as* a thread won't work. Use a queue or other means to communicate results back to the main thread.

Comment: @abc: use other, thread-based means to collect the data from the threads. Generators are not the way to go here.